# Cancelling form submission within jQuery .each() loop

Tags: jquery, forms, loops, each

I currently have a large poll made up of one form, 5 categories, a bunch of questions in each category and handful of radio button answers for each question.  The categories are each in a different fieldset and each category requires a varying minimum number of votes for the form to process.

Basically, on form submission, I'm trying to have jQuery go through each fieldset with an .each() loop and decide if the minimum number of votes per category has been met and if not, cancel the form submission.  What I have so far processes the categories just fine, but won't prevent the form from submitting if necessary.

```
$('#pollform').submit(function(event){

    var formsubmit = event;

    $('fieldset').each(function(formsubmit){
        catname     = $(this).children('input[name=catname]').val();    // Category name
        reqvotes    = $(this).children('input[name=catcount]').val();   // Minimum required number of votes for current category in loop
        numvotes    = $(this).children(':checked').size();              // Number of votes for current category in loop 

        // Check minimum number of votes against actual number cast.  Alert user and prevent form from submitting if necessary
        if (reqvotes > numvotes)
        {
            alert('You need to fill out at least '  + reqvotes + ' items for ' + catname  + '.');

            formsubmit.preventDefault();
        }
    });

});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try just returning false? Of course you have to do so from outside the each loop.

```
$('#pollform').submit(function(event){

    var stopsubmit = false;

    $('fieldset').each(function(formsubmit){
        if(stopsubmit) return;
        catname     = $(this).children('input[name=catname]').val();    // Category name
        reqvotes    = $(this).children('input[name=catcount]').val();   // Minimum required number of votes for current category in loop
        numvotes    = $(this).children(':checked').size();              // Number of votes for current category in loop 

        // Check minimum number of votes against actual number cast.  Alert user and prevent form from submitting if necessary
        if (reqvotes > numvotes)
        {
            alert('You need to fill out at least '  + reqvotes + ' items for ' + catname  + '.');

            stopsubmit=true;
        }
    });
    if(stopsubmit) return false;
});
```

I did not test this code.

Answer (score 0):

Add `return false;` just after the second last `});`, you only have to return false once, not each time while looping through that `each()` function.

Comment: Adding `return false;` after the second last `});` simply keeps the form from submitting at all, regardless of whether the minimum number of votes are cast or not.